# For a spherical pair $(G, H)$, which $G$-representations appear in $k[G/H]$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, spherical-varieties

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group (over some alg. closed field $k$ of char 0), and $H$ a subgroup such that $(G, H)$ is *spherical* (i.e., the Borel $B$ of $G$ has an open orbit on $G/H$). Then $k[G/H]$ is multiplicity-free as a $G$-module. I'm looking for a nice description of the irreducible $G$-representations it contains.

More precisely, let $\Lambda(G)$ be the lattice of integral weights for $G$ and $\Lambda_+(G)$ be the cone of dominant integral weights. For each $\lambda \in \Lambda_+(G)$ we have an irreducible representation $V_\lambda$. Let me write $\Lambda_+(G, H)$ for the set of $\lambda \in \Lambda_+(G)$ such that $V_\lambda$ appears in $k[G/H]$ (equivalently, such that $(V_\lambda)^H \ne 0$). The set $\Lambda_+(G, H)$ is a sub-monoid of $\Lambda_+(G)$ (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327654)). Playing around with some examples suggests the following:

> **Claim**: $\Lambda_+(G, H)$ is a lattice cone in $\Lambda(G)$, and its $\mathbb{Z}$-span is exactly the weights trivial on the $B$-stabiliser of a point in the open $B$-orbit on $G/H$.

Is this true? If so, is there a good reference that is easily digestible by non-experts like myself?

(Brion's paper "Spherical varieties" in the [1994 ICM proceedings](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1994.2/ICM1994.2.ocr.pdf), page 755, has a very general assertion about the sections of any $G$-equivariant line bundle on any spherical $G$-variety, which seems to be closely related; but I couldn't make head or tail of the proof, and surely there must be an easier approach for homogenous spherical varieties $G/H$ and trivial line bundles.)

Comment: To the title question, I’m guessing there should be an orbit method prediction as in Kobayashi ([2005](//doi.org/10.2977/prims/1145475221), §9). In principle this is for *unitary* representations, but he somewhat cryptically notes that others can be discussed “by applying Weyl’s unitary trick” (p. 505).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X_0=B/B_{x_0}=Bx_0$ be the open $B$-orbit in $X=G/H$. Then every character of $B$ which is trivial on $B_{x_0}$ yields a $B$-semiinvariant $f_\lambda$ on $X_0$. In general, it does not extend to a regular function on $X$. If it does, this means that $V_\lambda$ occurs in $k[X]$. So your second problems asks whether every $B$-semiinvariant on $X_0$ is a quotient of two regular $B$-semiinvariants on $X$. This is true if $X$ is quasiaffine (e.g., if $H$ is reductive) but false in general. Take, e.g., $G=SL(3,k)$ and $H=ker(\chi)$ where $\chi:B\to G_m$ is a character which is neither dominant nor antidominant (e.g. $\chi=a_{22}$). Then $V_\chi^H=0$ for all $\lambda$.

I don't know what you mean by lattice cone but if it means a monoid which is the intersection of a convex cone by a lattice then your first claim is true. This is a consequence of the normality of $X$. More precisely, let $\overline\Lambda_+$ be the intersection of the convex cone and the lattice generated by $\Lambda_+(G,H)$. It is called a saturation. An element $\lambda$ is in $\overline \Lambda_+$ if there is $m\ge1$ such that $m\lambda\in\Lambda_+(G,H)$. Now, since $\lambda$ is in the lattice generated by $\Lambda_+$ it corresponds to a rational $B$-semiinvariant $f_\lambda$ on $X$. The power $f_\lambda^m$ is regular. So $f_\lambda$ is regular and $\lambda\in\Lambda_+$.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Apologies for my vagueness about "lattice cone": the definition I had in mind was the monoid spanned by a linearly independent set of lattice vectors, i.e. a set of the form $\{ n_1 v_1 + \dots + n_r v_r : n_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\}$, where $v_i$ are vectors in $\Lambda(G)$ that are linearly independent in $\Lambda(G) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$. Does $\Lambda_+(G, H)$ necessarily have this form, at least if $H$ is reductive?

Comment: The answer to this question is related to the factoriality of $G/H$ which is related to the character group of $H$. In particular, if $H$ is semisimple then the monoid is free. Otherwise, you can find counterexamples on p. 149 of Krämer's paper "Sphärische Untergruppen...", the easiest being $G=SL(5)$ and $H=\mathbf G_m\cdot Sp(4)$. There the cone is $3$-dimensional with $4$ extremal reays.

Comment: Splendid, thanks!